# How can I Make System to open files when double click in Python?

Tags: python, macos

I want My Audio Files to Be Opened with my Python Program. So How Can I do it?

For Example: There is a Audio File on My Desktop. And Now If I Double Click it, It Opens in The Default Viewer. But I Want it to open it in my Program.

P.S. I am on Mac.

Comment: Have you tried clicking with the right mouse button, then "Open with", then search your program? You can set as default.

Comment: please elaborate on what do you want python todo

Comment: @PauloGuimarães I Tried But There was No Option To Select My Python File

Comment: @MrHola21 I wanted To Open A Mp3 File in My Audio Player made with python like other apps do when double clicking the file or when opening it.

Comment: moment, Have you created a program for that? By default the program search option is ".exe". If not, so click in "Show all files" instead. For sure your .py will be displayed.

Comment: @DivyanshAgrawal did you see my anwser?

Comment: And please, this is not a python issue. Change that. Your question should be "How can I set a custom program to open a file in YOUR-OPERATIONAL-SYSTEM.?" In your case this can be any program, it does not matter if it is python or whatever.

Comment: @PauloGuimarães Yeah, I found out that We Cannot Open Files directly from python when opening from system's Open With

Answer (score 0):

You can automate `double click` using `pyautogui` or `pynput` modules.

```py
from pyautogui import click
# you need to find out the value of x and y
# for that you can use pyautogui.position function
click(x, y)
```

Comment: bruh , finding the coordinates to the file would be more difficult xD

Comment: It does not make any sense. The files are in DESKTOP! Not in some Gui program.

Comment: @MrHola21, it is quite easy to find the coordinate of the file, place your cursor above the file and then run `pyautogui.position()` in the repl.

Comment: thats true but i find pyautogui a little heavy for this job , dont u think you  can just import the module `mouse`??

Comment: @ParasGupta the problem will not be solved from this as the file can be anywhere on the desktop or in the explorer. I want it to Open it in my Program when double clicked like opening file normally

Comment: Check out this ![tutorial](https://www.studytonight.com/tkinter/music-player-application-using-tkinter)

Comment: @ParasGupta I have created the Program and It is Opening Files using the tkinter button added but i want to open the file directly to open the file using system's open  with

Answer (score 0):

You can use a inbuild module called `os`

here's the doc:https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

the anwser to your problem is

`os.startfile(<path to your file>)`

Comment: thanks, but I was not looking for this. I wanted to open the mp3 file in my app when opened by double clicking the file